# Arrays, objects, classes to organize a test questionnaire program with multiple choice and true/false questions

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, vector

My question pertains to a school assignment, and I want to emphasize that I am not looking for someone to just give me the answer. However, I am looking for direction so I can solve this problem.

I made a test program consisting of multiple choice and true/false questions. I placed this information in 2 .txt files.  I'm organizing my code by class. I need to pull the information from the .txt file, output it to the screen, compare the user-input results with the test answers, and output a test score.

I know how to pull from a .txt file, but this has multiple choice and true-false questions that give string and char data. I considered creating arrays to store the questions and answers; however, I began to question whether there is a more efficient way to organize this data. It seems like I need way too many arrays, and perhaps 1 or 2 methods might suffice. I know how to calculate the test scores and do not need direction on that portion.

I'm developing this C++ code using the Microsoft Visual Studio IDE.

I've researched arrays, vectors, objects, classes, and many more topics that I thought may be related to this problem. I've read through my college textbook, listened to the lectures, watched YouTube videos, and consulted some programmers via Facebook.  I've googled questions and read answers on various C++ topics and programming examples. The fact that I'm still confused leads me to believe perhaps I'm just not grasping these concepts like I should be.

Can anyone with more expertise point me in the right direction?

********\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\**

**Here is the code I've created thus far:**

```
// Test.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution 
begins and ends there

#include "pch.h"
#include "QuestionMC.h"
#include "QuestionTF.h"

#include "QuestionMC.cpp"
#include "QuestionTF.cpp"

#include "TestBankMC.txt"
#include "TestBankTF.txt"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string question, answer;
    string q, a;
    int v;
    int value;

    cout << "====================================================\n";
    cout << "==                                                ==\n";
    cout << "==         WELCOME TO THE FBI ENTRANCE EXAM!      ==\n";
    cout << "==                                                ==\n";
    cout << "====================================================\n";
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "You will be asked a series of 11 questions consisting of both 
            True/False questions and multiple choice questions.\n";

   cout << "Please answer each question to the best of your ability\n\n\n" << 
           "Good luck!\n\n\n" << endl;


  //open file TestBankTF.txt
  ifstream file("TestBankTF.txt");

       // check for errors
        if (infile.fail()) {
            cerr << "Error Opening File" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }

        if (file.is_open())
        {
           string myTestBankTF[12];
           for (size_t i = 0; i < 12; i++){
               {
                    file >> myTestBankTF[i];
               }
        }

        // close TestBank.txt file
        infile.close();

    cout << "Please answer the following true or false questions with either 
            'true' or 'false': \n\n";
    cin >> question;

    string answersTF[3];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        if (myTestBankTF[12 == question)
        {
            cout << question << "\n\n";
            cout << "Answer: " << endl;
            cin >> answersTF[3];
        }
        else
        {
            cerr << question << "Error loading in myTestBankTF[].";
        }
    } 

    //open file TestBankMC.txt
    ifstream file("TestBankMC.txt");

    //check for errors
    if (infile.fail())
        {
            cerr << "Error opening file" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }

    if (file.is_open())
        {
            string myTestBankMC[71];

            for (size_t i = 0; i < 71; i++)
            {
                string myTestBankMC[i];
            }
        }

    // close TestBankMC.txt file
    infile.close();

    cout << "Please answer the following multiple choice questions with the 
            appropriate letter answer (A, B, C, D, or E): \n\n";
    cin >> question;

    string answersMC[11];
    string TestBankMC[71];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 71; i++)
        {
            if (myTestBankMC[71] == question)
                {
                    cout << question << "\n\n";
                    cout << "Answer: " << endl;
                    cin >> answersMC[11];
                    cin.ignore();
                }
            else
                {
                    cerr << question << "Error loading in myTestBankTF[].";
                }
        }

    return 0;

} // end of main function
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
// header file is class Questions' class and function declarations


    class Question
    {
public:
    Question();

    ~Question();

    Question(string, int, string)

    const std::string& getQuestion() const;

    const std::string& getAnswer() const;

    int getValue() const;

    virtual std::string printOptions() const; 


protected:
    std::string question, answer;
    int value;
};

#endif
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
// class Question's class and function definitions

Question::Question() {}

Question::~Question() {}

Question :: Question (std::string q, int v, std::string a)
     : question(std::move(q)), answer(std::move(a)), value(v) {}

Question :: const std::string& getQuestion() const
{
    return question;
}

Question :: const string& getAnswer() const
{
    return answer;
}

Question :: int getValue() const
{
    return value;
}
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
// header file is class QuestionMC's class and function declarations

class QuestionMC:: public Question
{
public:
     QuestionMC();

    ~QuestionMC();

    QuestionMC(const std::string&, int, const std::string&)

    void addOption(const std::string& option);

    string printOptions() const override {};

private:
    vector options;
    static const size_t MaxOptions = 6;
};

#endif
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
// subclass QuestionMC's class and member functions definitions

QuestionMC::QuestionMC(){}

QuestionMC::~QuestionMC(){}

QuestionMC(const string& q, int v, const string& a)
     : Question(q, v, a) {}

void QuestionMC::addOption(const string& option)
{
    if (options.size() < MaxOptions)
        options.push_back(option);
}

string QuestionMC::printOptions() const override
{
    ostringstream oss;
    char first = 'A';
    for (auto& option : options)
        oss << (first > 'A' ? "\n" : " ") << first++ << "." << option;
    return oss.str();
 }
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
// class and function declarations for subclass QuestionTF.h

class QuestionTF:public Question
{
   {
public:
    QuestionTF();

    ~QuestionTF();

    QuestionTF(const std::string&, int, const std::string&)

    std::string printOptions() const override {};  
};

#endif
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
// Class and functions definitions for subclass QuestionTF of class Question

QuestionTF::QuestionTF(){}

QuestionTF::~QuestionTF(){}

QuestionTF::QuestionTF(const std::string& q, int v, const std::string& a)
    : Question(q, v, a) {}

QuestionTF:: std::string printOptions() const override
{
    return "True/False";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your question is better suited for [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Avoid cross posting.

Comment: Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). In short, we can help you with a smaller precise problem, but all this is a bit to much.

Comment: Welcome to SO. One obvious thing, I saw on first glance: It's **very** unusual to `#include` cpp files.

Comment: `if (myTestBankTF[12 == question)` does not look right

Comment: `for (size_t i = 0; i < 71; i++)
            {
                string myTestBankMC[i];
            }` does not seem purposeful either

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I will try to make this answer ambiguous.

1. The data for the answer should have a format inside the txt file. Let's say "*" for start and end of question.  "+" for a right answer "-" from a wrong one.

   2. Have a class for a question and a class for answers. Make sure that that class has a list of Answers inside it
   3. Create a class for the question and add all the answers into it (Use formatting in part1 to cut parts of the txt input string into separate questions and answers)
   4. Have list of questions
   5. Display question one after another
   6. Calculate results

As after word you should use stack-overflow more in concrete and concise namer of questioning. ambiguous questions like these should be googled.

Answer (score 0):

I propose:

- A base class called cQuestion.  This will have code that applies to all kinds of questions
- A specialization of cQuestion called cTF.  Code for T/F questions
- A specialization of cQuestion called cMC.  Code for MC questions
- A class to contain all kinds of questions called cBank.

Your main method would look something like this:

```
cBank Bank

// read questions from txt file
Bank.Read( "TestBankTF.txt");
Bank.Read( "TestBankMC.txt");

// Loop over questions
for( cQuestion * Q : Bank )
{
   // Pose question
   Q->Pose();

   // Get Answer
   Q->Answer();

   // Calculate question score
   Q->Calculate();
}

// Display results
Bank.Results():
```

The code for a minimal implementation of this design is [available here](https://gist.github.com/JamesBremner/4193f46eec07fdae977c289386987ee2).